# sanitize sql statements for dbms_sql

Tags: oracle, sql-injection

ı have procedure that reads select statements from a table and execute them. it logs results to another table for reporting purpose.

if something like

```
insert into some table ... 
drop table table_name;
```

exist in my query table it might cause damage on my db.

here is a basic replacement of my code. how can i protect my data?

Is there a way restrict DBMS_SQL cursors to select statements only?

```
DECLARE
  l_cursor NUMBER DEFAULT DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
  l_cols   NUMBER DEFAULT 0;
  l_desc DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
  v_varchar2 VARCHAR2(4000) ;
  v_log_data VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_status   INTEGER;
BEGIN
  dbms_sql.parse( l_cursor, 'SELECT employee_id, last_name, to_char(hire_date) hire_date FROM EMPloyees where rownum<5', dbms_sql.native );
  l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_cursor);
  DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS( l_cursor, l_cols, l_desc );
  FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols
  LOOP
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(l_cursor, i, v_varchar2,4000);
  END LOOP;
  LOOP
    EXIT
  WHEN ( dbms_sql.fetch_rows(l_cursor) <= 0 );
    v_log_data := '';
    FOR i IN 1 .. l_cols
    LOOP
      DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(l_cursor, i, v_varchar2);    
      v_log_data :=v_log_data||l_desc(i).col_name || ':' ||v_varchar2||' ';
    END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_log_data);
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor);
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor);
END;
```

Comment: create a grant to users for read access only.

Comment: users will have insert and update grants for only query and log table.
however procedure will be run daily by admin user. since user will be modify sql statements in a table, İt'is still dangerous. So your suggestion is to create another user with read access only? can i grant users to run that procedure with access only rights?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Time to read some of the oracle documentation.